# Serving a Plone Subfolder on an Existing Website

Tags: nginx, plone, zope

I'm trying to serve a subfolder in a Plone site as part of an existing site. But when I do so certain features stop working e.g. the @@overview-controlpanel view is inaccessible.

For example:

The existing domain is example.com. An existing site is served there. My goal is it to serve localhost:8080/plone/subfolder on the url example.com/mysite using a reverse proxy.

From how I understand VirtualHostMonster I should be able to do this with the following nginx config:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com;

    client_max_body_size 25m;

    location /events {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/example.com/plone/subfolder/VirtualHostRoot/_vh_mysite/;
    }
}
```

This actually works pretty well, except for the fact that I cannot access @@overview-controlpanel. I get a 404.

How do I have to form my proxy_pass url using VirtualHostMonster to serve my site under example.com/mysite without error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have it both ways; you can serve the subfolder as part of your site, but for certain things you *have* to have access the site root.

Set up a separate, private domain to access the root folder like a normal site, and access the control panel from there. Control panel views are normally tied to the Plone portal root object, with good reason.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Nginx config so it serves the Plone site root as /events. And in your Plone site, choose 'subfolder' as your default page (you will need to authorized to use Folder contents as default page in the ZMI: default_page_types parameter in portal_properties / site_properties).

Comment: I did that before, but it messes with some modules. The toolbar where you can add new items will not work on the right context, for example.

Comment: Right. What about creating a collection in the site root that will display the contents from /subfolder, and use this collection as default page.

Comment: Does not work in my case because it messes with the theme that I am required to use. Now that could be improved upon, but it seems harder than using a separate domain as suggested by @MartijnPieters.